# Does Python automatically replace * 2 with << 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, python-internals

I saw suggestions (see e.g. [Is multiplication and division using shift operators in C actually faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357038/is-multiplication-and-division-using-shift-operators-in-c-actually-faster)) that you should not manually replace multiplication with the shift operator, because the compiler has to do it automatically and shift operators decrease readability. I have written a simple test to check this:

```
import numpy as np
import time

array1 = np.random.randint(size=10 ** 6, low=0, high=10 ** 5)
array2 = np.zeros((10 ** 6,), dtype=np.int)

total = 0.0
for i in range(100):
    start = time.clock()
    for j in range(len(array2)):
        array2[j] = array1[j] * 2
    total += time.clock() - start
print("*2 time = " + str(round(total / 10, 5)) + " ms")


total = 0.0
for i in range(100):
    start = time.clock()
    for j in range(len(array2)):
        array2[j] = array1[j] << 1
    total += time.clock() - start
print("<< 1 time = " + str(round(total / 10, 5)) + " ms")


total = 0.0
for i in range(100):
    start = time.clock()
    for j in range(len(array2)):
        array2[j] = array1[j] // 2
    total += time.clock() - start
print("//2 time = " + str(round(total / 10, 5)) + " ms")


total = 0.0
for i in range(100):
    start = time.clock()
    for j in range(len(array2)):
        array2[j] = array1[j] >> 1
    total += time.clock() - start
print(">> 1 time = " + str(round(total / 10, 5)) + " ms")
```

I used equivalent operations (`* 2` is equivalent to `<< 1` and `// 2` to `>> 1`) and here is the result:

```
*2 time = 5.15086 ms
<< 1 time = 4.76214 ms
//2 time = 5.17429 ms
>> 1 time = 4.79294 ms
```

What is wrong? Is my testing method wrong? Is the time measurement wrong? Or does Python not perform such optimizations (and, if yes, should I be afraid of that)? I used cPython 3.4.2 x64 on Win 8.1 x64.

Comment: You can use [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) to look at the bytecode, and [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to get more accurate timing.

Comment: *"I saw suggestions, that you should not manually replace multiplication with shift operator, because compiler have to do it automatically and shift operators decrease readability."* - where did you see these suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357038/is-multiplication-and-division-using-shift-operators-in-c-actually-faster for example

Comment: Wondering why you divide by 10 when you run them 100 times. Are you on Unix?

Comment: Python is byte-code interpreted and byte-code is a representation of the source and should not be optimized. The optimization might happen on runtime. E.g. LLVM does not create this shift-operation when LLVM-IR is created. Just when the entire stuff goes to the CPU and the real instructions are created. Thats why you see these optimizations e.g. in C and C++ compilers and JITs, not CPython.

Comment: There should be 100 instead of 10, I forget one zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This optimization doesn't occur at bytecode level:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(lambda x: x*2)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              7 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(lambda x: x<<1)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 BINARY_LSHIFT
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

The [dis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module allows you to show you what happens "inside" Python when your code is executed or, more precisely, what exactly is executed. The output shows that the `*` operator is mapped to `BINARY_MULTIPLY` and the `<<` operator is mapped to `BINARY_LSHIFT`. These two bytecode operations are implemented in C.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain in more detail what this is showing.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) (to look at the bytecode equivalent of functions) and [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) (more robust timing than trying to do it manually using `time`) can give you a better idea of what's going on internally. Test script:

```
def multiply(x):
    return x * 2

def l_shift(x):
    return x << 1

def divide(x):
    return x // 2

def r_shift(x):
    return x >> 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import dis
    import timeit

    methods = (multiply, l_shift, divide, r_shift)
    setup = 'from __main__ import {}'.format(
        ', '.join(method.__name__ for method in methods),
    )
    for method in methods:
        print method.__name__
        dis.dis(method)
        print timeit.timeit(
            'for x in range(10): {}(x)'.format(method.__name__),
            setup=setup,
        )
        print
```

And outputs (CPython v2.7.6 on Windows 7):

```
multiply
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 RETURN_VALUE        
2.22467834797

l_shift
  5           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 BINARY_LSHIFT       
              7 RETURN_VALUE        
2.05381004158

divide
  8           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE 
              7 RETURN_VALUE        
2.43717730095

r_shift
 11           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 BINARY_RSHIFT       
              7 RETURN_VALUE        
2.08359396854
```

Clearly Python is **not** replacing the multiplication/division operations with the equivalent bit shifts (e.g. `BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE` is not replaced by `BINARY_RSHIFT`), although it looks like such an optimisation *could* give performance improvements. As to *why* the bit shift is faster, see e.g. [Speeds of << >> multiplication and division](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/234967/110531) on Programmers.

Answer (score 4):

Only in very limited circumstances could CPython implement these optimisations. The reason being that CPython is a ducked-typed language.

Given the code fragment `x * 2`, this can mean very different things dependent on the value of `x`. If `x` is an integer than it does indeed have the same meaning as `x << 1`. However, if `x` is a float or a string or a list or any other class that implements `__mul__` in its own unique way then it most certainly doesn't have the same meaning as `x << 1`. For example, `"a" * 2 == "aa"`. So unless the value of `x` is known at compile time then this optimisation cannot be made. If the value of `x` *is* known beforehand then the entire operation can be optimised away eg.

```
In [3]: import dis

In [4]: def f():
   ...:     return 2 * 2
   ...: 

In [5]: dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (4)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see that the compiler has performed the operation itself and just returns the constant value `4`.