# How do I convert a char array [example 42] to the int equivilant [int 42] using bit manipulation?

Tags: c, arrays, string, bit-manipulation

say I have a string 42\0 0b0011010000110001000000000 [or an array without a null terminator 42 0b00110100001100010] and I want to convert it to 42 0b00101010 with bit manipulation. How would I go about this?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to convert `"42"` to `42`?  If so, that's what things like `sscanf` and `strtol` are for.

Comment: If the null terminator is optional, does that mean it's always a 2-digit number?

Comment: @samgak, it could be 1, it could be 1000. Say N digits.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth , I want to know how to do it with bit manipulation. I know of a million other ways, but I want to learn how to do it this way as well.

Comment: If it has 1000 digits, what output data-type are you using?

Comment: But in general, a string of digits `"abcd"` is equal to the integer value `1000*a + 100*b + 10*c + d`.  Information on implementing multiplication/addition via bit-manipulation is readily available on the web.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, it's just a figure of speech.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, without any checks that the number is a digit, is negative, or will be out of range, you can do this:

```
int myatoi( const char * s )
{
    int result = 0;
    while( *s )
    {
        result <<= 1;
        result += (result << 2);
        result += (*s++ & 0x0f);
    }
    return result;
}
```

*Caveat*: The use of addition doesn't strictly meet the requirement that this be achieved with bit operations.

Comment: I like the elegance of this answer. There's no way to get rid of the addition, right?

Comment: No easy way.  I think any solution you could come up with would be more computationally expensive than this.  Usually the reason we jump to bit operations for math is when there's a performance gain that the compiler won't get through aggressive optimizations.  For example, a multiply by 10 might be converted to bit shifts by the compiler, but it wouldn't turn `(*s - '0')` into `(*s & 0x0f)` because they would give different output if presented with bad data.

Comment: yeah I took a look at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-two-numbers-without-using-arithmetic-operators/ and there seems to be more steps than it would take to just through it through the ALU. I'm just doing it as an intellectual exercise. Thanks for your help. I never knew you could iterate through a  char* the way you did. Super cool.

Comment: Regarding performance, and expressing operations the way we _think_ is better, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6357038/1553090

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a read. I thought you were kind of stuck up before, but you were just pointing out that I wasn't doing what I set out to do. Thanks so much for your input!

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to @paddy 's answer, for a purely bitwise way to accomplish this is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bitwiseadd(int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *array = argv[1];
    int result = 0;

    while(*array)
    {
        result <<= 1;
        result = bitwiseadd(result, result<<2);
        result = bitwiseadd(result, *array++ & 0x0f);
    }
    printf("Value is:%d.\n", result);
    return 0;
}

int bitwiseadd(int x, int y)
{
    if( y == 0 )
        return x;
    else
        return bitwiseadd(x^y,(x&y)<<1);
}
```

Comment: @paddy , check this out :)

Comment: @samgak , check this out :)

Comment: Does the address increment count? :)

Comment: @samgak the *array++ is the same thing as array[index]. It's super cool.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the answer.

First we need to strip the 0010 off the top, as in the ASCII table the binary of the char is 0010+the binary value of the number, 1 is 00100001 etc
So, you would do 
    00001111 & char;
so

```
int tmpValue = 15 & char;
```

Next, you would get the size of the array.

```
int n = strlen(chararray);
```

working left to right of the array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
        char array[4] = "123\0";
        int total = 0;
        int index;

        int arraysize = strlen(array);
        for(index=0; index < arraysize; index++)
        {
                total = ((total << 3) + (total << 1));
                total += (15 & array[index]);
        }
        printf("Value is: %d", total);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You said you wanted bit manipulation, but then you're multiplying by return  from `exp`...  You can achieve multiplication using bit shifts, you know.

Comment: @paddy well no one else is giving any answer so I decided to give it a shot. Excuse me for trying. I'm figuring it out as I go and I will update accordingly.

Comment: ANDing with 15 is a nice trick. You can avoid the call to pow by multiplying the current total by 10 using bitshifts, (hint: x * 10 = x * 8 + x * 2), then adding (15 & array[index])

Comment: @samgak thanks, I'm going to go eat dinner then finish it up :)

Comment: @samgak, it would be (x<<3) + (x<<1) ?

Comment: @samgak, just did that. the total is off by 1 order of magnitude. 123 is coming out to 1230

Comment: Your loop condition should be index < arraysize. The last digit you process is index = arraysize - 1 because C arrays start from 0

Comment: @samgak just did that and now I'm getting inconsistant output. I'm pushing some bits in to the total that shouldn't be there. weird.

Comment: Your char array isn't large enough, you need an extra byte for the null

Comment: You did not provided enough storage to null-terminate your string.  The string is 3 bytes plus 1 for the terminator, but your array can only hold 3 bytes, leading to undefined behaviour of `strlen`

Comment: @samgak there is no way to do it without first null terminating right? Or else it starts throwing some undefined behavior?

Comment: Your function has to know when to stop processing digits. So you can either have a null-terminated string, or else you can have an array of digit characters and a digit count stored with it (that's how Pascal stores strings).

Comment: @samgak alright cool ty, that's what I figured. I took a look at how to add with bitwise operators and it's more of a hassle. I'll finish this up tomorrow probably with pure bitwise operators :)