# How to do shift right (">>" operator in C++) in OpenCV? (Seems only &, |, ^, etc, but no >> operator)

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV and need to do a shift right for each pixel in a `Mat`. For example,

```
Mat m = ...;
int numbits = get_num_bits_from_the_user_input(...);
Mat a = m >> numbits; // this
```

However, I only see operators like &, |, ^, and so on (as well as function name like bitwise_and, bitwise_or, etc) in the [official manual](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaa0f00d98b4b5edeaeb7b8333b2de353b). I even [dig into the source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp) but do not find the bit shift operations.

You know, this is a very common and useful operator. So how can I get that?

Of course I can use a division, like `m / thedivisor`. However, as all know that, the division is far far slower than the bitwise operations. So I do not want to use it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357038/is-multiplication-and-division-using-shift-operators-in-c-actually-faster

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe thanks for the reply! however, the number is given as a dynamic variable, not a constant. let me edit my question to reflect it.

Comment: I don't know if OpenCV supports bit-wise shifts at the pixel level. You _could_ loop through the `cv::Mat` using a [`cv::MatIterator_`](https://riptutorial.com/opencv/example/23884/alternative-pixel-access-with-matiterator), get each pixel (depending on the number of channels in your image) and shift the value manually...

Comment: @stateMachine sure but that would be super slow... you know, for things like division or bitwise and, it uses a lot of speed up so it is quite good (e.g. i see it uses opencl under the scene in some cases)

Comment: I've searched for a bit and there's not mention of _bit-wise shifts_ in the docs, so I really doubt there's support for it, but I honestly don't know (I've used the C++ implementation of OpenCV for a couple of years and never saw anything like that). So at least you've got the iterator option. That approach should take advantage of a [continuous](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-iscontinuous) image in memory and be a little bit faster than a regular `cv::Mat::at` access. Hope someone comes with a definitive answer because I want to know too.

Comment: "However, as all know that, the division is far far slower than the bitwise operations" I would say that all don't know that, because it is not always true. Optimizers are very good at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357038/is-multiplication-and-division-using-shift-operators-in-c-actually-faster

Comment: If you go all the way down in the source code, you would notice that all those operations you mentioned just calls 2 levels of for loop and do operations on each elements. So if you want a bitwise shift operator, just overload them and do some for loops.

Comment: You can try `cv::Mat::forEach<T>(Functor)`

Comment: @김선달 thanks for the reply. but that does not utilize SIMD imho

Comment: @RetiredNinja please correct me if I am wrong: imho, i*2 or i*127 can be optimized. but i*a where `a` is a value that is inputted from the user at runtime cannot be optimized.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep imho it calls opencl: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp#L71.

Comment: @ch271828n In that case, you have to use other libraries instead of OpenCV

Comment: @김선달 opencv does do a lot of optimizations if they provide it. but unfortunately seems not provide shift operator

Comment: @ch271828n My bad, I disabled OpenCL, and it goes [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/f88fdf6a1bec7fcd98ad9c447f55e81f81035014/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp#L620), and eventually calls [carotene::vtransform](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/f88fdf6a1bec7fcd98ad9c447f55e81f81035014/3rdparty/carotene/src/vtransform.hpp#L625)

Comment: @Ranoiaetep oh i see. sometimes opencl can be disabled in some env. but even if this, its vtransform is quite fast - seems it uses prefetch as well as SIMD (128bit)